# Satellite position computation using Runge-Kutta 4

Tags: python, runge-kutta, orbital-mechanics, satellite-navigation

my issue is related to Runge-Kutta 4 (RK4) method and the correct iteration steps required for the state vector of an orbiting satellite. 
The below code (in Python) describes the motion based on the description as per this link (http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/GLONASS_Satellite_Coordinates_Computation):

```
    if total_step_number != 0:   
        for i in range(1, total_step_number+1):                             
            #Calculate k1                
            k1[0] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[0] / radius**3) \
             + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[0] * (1 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
             + XYZDDot[0] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ[0]) + (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot[1])
            k1[1] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[1] / radius**3) \
             + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[1] * (1 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
             + XYZDDot[1] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ[1]) - (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot[0])
            k1[2] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[2] / radius**3) \
             + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[2] * (3 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
             + XYZDDot[2]

            #Intermediate step to bridge k1 to k2
            XYZ2[0] = XYZ[0] + (XYZDot[0] * h / 2) + (k1[0] * h**2 / 8)
            XYZDot2[0] = XYZDot[0] + (k1[0] * h / 2)
            XYZ2[1] = XYZ[1] + (XYZDot[1] * h / 2) + (k1[1] * h**2 / 8)
            XYZDot2[1] = XYZDot[1] + (k1[1] * h / 2)
            XYZ2[2] = XYZ[2] + (XYZDot[2] * h / 2) + (k1[2] * h**2 / 8)
            XYZDot2[2] = XYZDot[2] + (k1[2] * h / 2)
            radius = np.sqrt((XYZ2[0]**2)+(XYZ2[1]**2)+(XYZ2[2]**2))

             ....
```

There is more code however I want to limit what I show for now since it's the intermediate steps I'm most interested in resolving. Basically, for those familiar with state vectors and using RK4, you can see that the position and velocity is updated in the intermediate step, but not the acceleration. My question is related to the calculation required in order to update too the acceleration. It would begin:

```
XYZDDot[0] = ...
XYZDDot[1] = ...
XYZDDot[2] = ...
```

...but what exactly comes after is not very clear. Any advice welcome.

Below is the full code:

```
        for j in h_step_values:
            h = j    
            if h > 0:
                one_way_iteration_steps = one_way_iteration_steps -1
            elif h < 0:
                one_way_iteration_steps = one_way_iteration_steps +1
                XYZ = initial_XYZ
            #if total_step_number != 0:   
            for i in range(0, one_way_iteration_steps):                             
                #Calculate k1                
                k1[0] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[0] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[0] * (1 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[0] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ[0]) + (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot[1])
                k1[1] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[1] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[1] * (1 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[1] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ[1]) - (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot[0])
                k1[2] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ[2] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ[2] * (3 - (5*(XYZ[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[2]

                #Intermediate step to bridge k1 to k2
                XYZ2[0] = XYZ[0] + (XYZDot[0] * h / 2) + (k1[0] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[0] = XYZDot[0] + (k1[0] * h / 2)
                XYZDDot2[0] = XYZDDot[0] + (k1[0] * h / 2)
                XYZ2[1] = XYZ[1] + (XYZDot[1] * h / 2) + (k1[1] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[1] = XYZDot[1] + (k1[1] * h / 2)
                XYZ2[2] = XYZ[2] + (XYZDot[2] * h / 2) + (k1[2] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[2] = XYZDot[2] + (k1[2] * h / 2)
                radius = np.sqrt((XYZ2[0]**2)+(XYZ2[1]**2)+(XYZ2[2]**2))

                #Calculate k2  
                k2[0] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[0] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[0] * (1 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[0] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ2[0]) + (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot2[1])
                k2[1] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[1] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[1] * (1 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[1] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ2[1]) - (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot2[0])
                k2[2] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[2] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[2] * (3 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[2]

                #Intermediate step to bridge k2 to k3
                XYZ2[0] = XYZ[0] + (XYZDot[0] * h / 2) + (k2[0] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[0] = XYZDot[0] + (k2[0] * h / 2)
                XYZ2[1] = XYZ[1] + (XYZDot[1] * h / 2) + (k2[1] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[1] = XYZDot[1] + (k2[1] * h / 2)
                XYZ2[2] = XYZ[2] + (XYZDot[2] * h / 2) + (k2[2] * h**2 / 8)
                XYZDot2[2] = XYZDot[2] + (k2[2] * h / 2)
                radius = np.sqrt((XYZ2[0]**2)+(XYZ2[1]**2)+(XYZ2[2]**2))

                #Calculate k3  
                k3[0] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[0] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[0] * (1 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[0] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ2[0]) + (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot2[1]) 
                k3[1] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[1] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[1] * (1 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[1] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ2[1]) - (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot2[0])
                k3[2] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[2] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[2] * (3 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[2]

                #Intermediate step to bridge k3 to k4
                XYZ2[0] = XYZ[0] + (XYZDot[0] * h) + (k3[0] * h**2 / 2)
                XYZDot2[0] = XYZDot[0] + (k3[0] * h)
                XYZ2[1] = XYZ[1] + (XYZDot[1] * h) + (k3[1] * h**2 / 2)
                XYZDot2[1] = XYZDot[1] + (k3[1] * h)
                XYZ2[2] = XYZ[2] + (XYZDot[2] * h) + (k3[2] * h**2 / 2)
                XYZDot2[2] = XYZDot[2] + (k3[2] * h)
                radius = np.sqrt((XYZ2[0]**2)+(XYZ2[1]**2)+(XYZ2[2]**2))

                #Calculate k4 
                k4[0] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[0] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[0] * (1 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[0] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ2[0]) + (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot2[1])
                k4[1] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[1] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[1] * (1 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[1] + (cs.OMEGAE_DOT**2 * XYZ2[1]) - (2 * cs.OMEGAE_DOT * XYZDot2[0]) 
                k4[2] = (-cs.GM_GLONASS * XYZ2[2] / radius**3) \
                 + ((3/2) * cs.C_20 * cs.GM_GLONASS * cs.SEMI_MAJOR_AXIS_GLONASS**2 * XYZ2[2] * (3 - (5*(XYZ2[2]**2) / (radius**2))) / radius**5) \
                 + XYZDDot[2]


                for p in range(3):
                    XYZ[p] = XYZ[p] + XYZDot[p] * h + h**2 * ((k1[p] + 2*k2[p] + 2*k3[p] + k4[p]) / 12)
                    XYZDot[p] = XYZDot[p] + (h * (k1[p] + 2*k2[p] + 2*k3[p] + k4[p]) / 6)

                radius = np.sqrt((XYZ[0])**2 + (XYZ[0])**2 + (XYZ[0])**2)
```

Comment: why not (current step velocity - previous step velocity) / time_interval? But if the acceleration does not appear in your equations why do you want to calculate it?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, the accelaration does appear in the equations (they are referred to the XYZDDot). The only difference with the accelaration, wrt the velocity and position is that the initial values are taken for the accelaration, but then thereafter never updated. Whereas the "#Intermediate step..." section deals with the updates of the velocity and position. I was told that updating the accelaration makes very little difference and costs more processing time (probably negligible anyway).

Comment: However at the moment I experience a "split" between adjacent blocks of data: one is propogating forward 15 minutes, the other backwards 15 minutes. The points at either end should (very nearly) match. But there's an offset and I can't locate why the iterations behave like this.

Comment: can it not be that the acceleration is constant? this is space after all

Comment: @Ev.Kounis. I agree, if not constant then negligible increases. I just wanted to see if there were a solution and if so, could I use it to test for this unknown discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you are solving is of the type

```
ddot x = a(x)
```

where `a(x)` is the acceleration which is computed in your `k1` computation. Indeed, the first order system would be

```
dot v = a(x)
dot x = v
```

The RK4 implementation thus starts with

```
k1 = a(x)
l1 = v

k2 = a(x+l1*h/2) = a(x+v*h/2)
l2 = v+k1*h/2
```

etc. The use of the `l1,l2,...` seems implicit in the code, inserting these linear combinations directly where they occur.

---

In short, you are not missing the acceleration computation, it is the main part of the code fragment.

---

**Update: (8/22)** To come closer to the intention of the  intermediate bridge steps, the abstract code should read ( with `(* .. *)` denoting comments or unnecessary computations)

```
k1 = a(x)                    (* l1 = v *)

x2 = x + v*h/2               (* v2 = v + k1*h/2 *)

k2 = a(x2)                   (* l2 = v2 *)

x3 (* = x + l2*h/2 *) 
   = x + v*h/2 + k1*h^2/4    (* v3 = v + k2*h/2 *)

k3 = a(x3)                   (* l3 = v3 *)

x4 (* = x + l3*h *)
   = x + v*h + k2*h^2/2      (* v4 = v + k3*h *)

k4 = a(x4)                   (* l4 = v4 *)


delta_v = ( k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4 ) * h/6

delta_x (* = ( l1+2*(l2+l3)+l4 ) * h/6 *)
        = v*h + (k1+k2+k3) * h^2/6
```

Comment: So from your answer then the iteration should be, for example: XYZDDot[0] = XYZDDot[0] + (k1[0] * h / 2) ?

Comment: No, `XYZDDOT` is a measured and transmitted outside constant. At least for the integration interval, the gravitational forces of the moon and sun are constants. What changes appreciably is the position relative to earth, and the resulting forces are recomputed for every intermediate step.

Comment: So in effect the accelaration doesn't need to be updated, and is just left as is. If that's the case, then it is not clear what other factors are leading to the difference between the forward integration by 15 minutes, and backward integration (on the next ephemeris block) by 15 minutes. These two values should be quasi the same, but they're not.

Comment: the full code is added, so you can see whether this corresponds to your interpretation of the RK4 process. As you can see, there are no updates to acceleration (XYZDDot of XYZDDot2).

Comment: Flying forward for 15min and flying backward for 15 min should give different results. Or is that in combination so that the second should integration should lead back to the initial point? -- Anyway, although superficially similar, the implemented method is not RK4. Thus it is not clear if its order remains 4 or is 2.

Comment: The GLONASS RINEX navigation blocks are broadcast in blocks of 30 minutes. The parameters in each block (e.g. pos, vel, acc) are for the central point of that particular block. RK4 is applied backwards 15 minutes and forward 15 minutes, iterating along the way to determine the position of the satellite at each epoch (i.e. every 1s). So one block at 12:00 employs RK4 to iterate forward till 12:15. The next epoch block at 12:30, uses RK4 to iterate backward till 12:15. Therefore, these two points (both at 12:15) should be the same. In my case, I have a discrepancy.

Comment: As I said, as you add an order 2 perturbation to the usual RK4 method, this may add to an order 1 error over the full integration. Thus the question is, how large are the errors and do they diminish using the proper method. You could also examine the error under varying time steps, the error order should be clearly visible. It is also not necessary to take the sampling step 1s as time step, you can also take, as example, 10s and interpolate the samples in between.

Comment: I tried with varying "h" steps (see code). The optimal solution where the errors between epoch crossover occurs is with 1s. In my code above, I'm assuming I can add at every intermediate step (between the k's) the XYZDDot2 which has been missing. I've not tested for this yet. I need to determine also what the XYZDDot2 equals at every stage; this goes back to my original question. The error between the crossover depends on the satellite, and can be quantified in terms of elevation degrees, typicall between 0.5 and 2 degrees (at crossover this is seen on an elevation plot as a vertical line).

Comment: ...and this is the point at either 15minutes in the future or 15 minues behind, on the next block. Another way to get around this would be to create the array from parameters anyway, and then "smooth" the data using a polyfit. That could achieve the desirable results, but the RK4 brough to a clean state would be preferred.

Comment: `XYZDOT2` is what I called `l2` and is not needed in the true RK4 method. And is then reused for `l3` and `l4`, as `XYZ2` is used for `x2` and then for `x3` and `x4`: Thus the `2` has nothing to do with the second derivative.